# flex state basedOn multiple states

Tags: apache-flex, states

Is it possible, in flex, to assign multiple states as base for another state?
Say I have state "stateA" that adds a button "buttonA" and state "stateB" that adds a button "buttonB". Is it possible to create a state "stateC" that is based on state "stateA" and "stateB"?
If not, is there a workaround to accomplish that?

Also notice that the button IDs should be "buttonA" and "buttonB" and I can't have several buttons in different states with the same ID ...

Here is an example of what I want:

```
<mx:State name="stateA">
 <mx:AddChild>
  <mx:Button id="buttonA" />
 </mx:AddChild>
</mx:State>
<mx:State name="stateB">
 <mx:AddChild>
  <mx:Button id="buttonB" />
 </mx:AddChild>
</mx:State>
<mx:State name="stateC" basedOn="stateA,stateB">
</mx:State>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. But I seem to have a work around for this particular case:

- `stateC` has both `buttonA` and `buttonB`
- `stateA`, based on `stateC`, removes `buttonB`
- `stateB`, based on `stateC`, removes `buttonA`

Would that suffice your use-case?

Comment: Thinking outside the box ... very nice!